# WP Gallery Image Page Issue When 2 galleries share one image

Tags: posts, images, gallery

All attached images are stored in WP_POST table and have PARENT_POST which is only one.

So if I put some image in one gallery the image will belong to that gallery(post). If I add the same Image in another gallery(post) and open the image page, than all next and prev image links will be from the first gallery.

How Can I have 2 galleries and when I open the image page to fetch only the images which are in that gallery(post).

Thank You

Comment: How are next/previous links implemented in your theme?

Comment: next_image_link() && previous_image_link

Comment: The default theme twentyfourteen works the same way and has the same problem.

Comment: Those functions are quite clearly coded with shared post parent in mind. Which pages precisely do you mean? Image's attachment page? If you left page with gallery it wouldn't know which gallery you want to cycle through...

Comment: Those function are taking the parent post from the WP_POST. 

So I have 2 posts with different galleries. If i have 1 image which is the same for both galleries. When I open the image which will open IMAGE.PHP. There next and prev Image will be the one where the image was added first. 

I want somehow when I open the image from any gallery next and prev images to be the one from where the gallery was open. I don't know how I can do it.

Comment: This is not trivial. You'll have to roll your own functions for it from scratch and somehow pass gallery info between pageloads. It might make more sense to go with solution that cycles images without leaving page with gallery.

Comment: To take the attachment url I use get_attachment_link(). Is it possible when the link is created to send a variable also the post ID from where I am comming. Like that I can fetch all images which are in that gallery and see which of them are prev and next